# still persists: INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I keep encountering this pesky error. I've understood what the error means, that you're inserting a value in a table that is not present from the other table. I've tried manually passing the `makerap` string, and placing it in a string variable first before I would pass it. but I still keep getting this error.

```
string whoAdd = "makerap";

//txnDetails.WhoAdded = "makerap";
txnDetails.WhoAdded = whoAdd;
```

The moment I comment out the second line above, the ff. error pops up:

```
Procedure or function 'sp_AddNewTxnDetails' expects parameter '@WhoAdded', which was not supplied.
```

which would make complete sense, because I removed the WhoAdded parameter from the list of parameters being passed. But when I try to pass the WhoAdded parameter again, it's when things DO NOT make sense.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__tb_Transa__Recor__4E88ABD4". The conflict occurred in database "CBCFX", table "dbo.tb_Users", column 'UserName'. The statement has been terminated.
```

I have checked, double-checked, and even TRIPLE-CHECKED that there IS an entry in my `tb_Users` with its UserName primary key as `makerap` .

any idea on what could be causing this?

**EDIT1**: adding whole stored proc...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_AddNewTxnDetails]
@BranchCode nvarchar(5),
@AccountNo nvarchar(20) = null,
@ReferenceNo nvarchar(20),
@TxnDate nvarchar(20),
@TxnType nvarchar(5),
@CCYCode nvarchar(5),
@CCYAmount numeric(18,2),
@RecordStatus nvarchar(5),
--@RecordStatusDate nvarchar(20),
@RecordStatusApprovedBy nvarchar(20),
--@DateAdded nvarchar(20),
@WhoAdded nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
IF @AccountNo = ''
    SET @AccountNo = null

INSERT INTO tb_TransactionDetails
(
    BranchCode, AccountNo,
    ReferenceNo, TxnDate,
    TxnType, CCYCode,
    CCYAmount, RecordStatus,
    RecordStatusDate, RecordStatusDateApprovedBy,
    DateAdded, WhoAdded
)

VALUES
(
    @BranchCode, @AccountNo,
    @ReferenceNo, @TxnDate,
    @TxnType, @CCYCode,
    @CCYAmount, @RecordStatus,
    SYSDATETIME(), @RecordStatusApprovedBy,
    SYSDATETIME(), @WhoAdded
)

END
```

**EDIT2:**
what is more crazy is that all of this actually worked yesterday, I managed to add 3 records no problem. I'm pretty sure I didn't touch any of the codes for today, and now it won't work anymore.

Comment: What does your SP look like? If you look into the constraints on your table, what columns do `FK__tb_Transa__Recor__4E88ABD4` contain?

Comment: There MUST be a difference between the value in the db and your string. Are your column types the same, no additional spaces somewhere around, simple misspelling... ?

Comment: So, I dont think that you've proved that `@WhoAdded` is the culprit here.  If you comment that parameter out in your sproc are you able to  run the sproc? (forget the c# at this point, just run it from the db, your error is there)

Comment: I agree with paqogomez. Try sp_help tb_TransactionDetails (or simply highlight the table name in SSMS and hit Alt-F1) and look for the contraint_keys on constraint FK__tb_Transa__Recor__4E88ABD4.

Comment: Also check for any triggers on the table. I've seen `INSTEAD OF` triggers that basically stuff things up when a new column has been added because they aren't catered for in the trigger text.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I have actually tried to use `sp_help earlier, but I couldn't use it. turns out, I wasn't really paying attention to the whole window. there's a big scroll bar at the side of the Results tab. I scrolled down and managed to find that foreign key code. turns out, it was NOt pointing to @WhoAdded, but to another parameter.

Comment: so yeah, CORRECTION. I HAVE changed the code earlier XD I fixed it now, I commented out the stuff that I added earlier into the code, and it works now. a bit off-topic: I see in paqogomez's post that he highlighted the foreign key code. how do you do that highlight in posts?

Comment: `back tick` its under the `tilde` :)  Most of the same mark up you can do in the posts, you can do here.

Comment: So does that mean you've found and fixed the error?

Comment: yup, I have. earlier I added an extra parameter `@RecordStatusApprovedBy` that also references `tb_Users`. but in the code behind, just for testing I was inserting `""` (blank string) into the `@RecordStatusApprovedBy` parameter, in which `""` does not exist in my `tb_Users`. so I removed that for now, and my code works again. @paqogomez thanks for persisting me to use the `sp_help` LOL XD